# How Can I get instagram images long and latitude or location information?

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
api = InstagramAPI(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
recent_media = api.user_recent_media(user_id = user_id, count=5)

for media in recent_media[0]:
    print 'post_id :' ,media.id
    print 'post_image : ', media.images['standard_resolution']
    print 'post_created_at :' ,media.created_time
    print 'caption :' ,media.caption
    print 'tags :' ,media.tags
    print 'post_link :' ,media.link
    print 'post_coordinates :' ,media.???????
    print 'like_count :' ,media.like_count
    print 'comment_count :' ,media.comment_count
```

I can list the information about a media for specific user. I couldn't figure out how to get "location information"(long/lat) of any given instagram post. Beside this I couldn't find detailed documentation about python-instagram sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the Python client implementation](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/master/instagram/models.py), it looks like media that has a location would expose it at:

```
media.location.name
media.location.point.latitude
media.location.point.longitude
```

Not every media item has a location, and a location can have a name but no latitude and longitude.